# is enclosing methods within self, a design pattern in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

while learning, I have seen this pattern in most of the examples, where within a class there is method
self.method , which instantiates the class it is defined in and call other instance methods. what are the actual purpose of using this?

```
    class Work
      def initialize (params, options = {}) 
          @params = params 
      end 

      def doWork
          //do something here 
      end

      def self.doWork(params)
          new(params).doWork
      end
    end
```

Comment: Read up on factory methods. This particular example is kind of pointless but in other cases the factory method may change the arguments being passed to `new` and therefore customize its behavior.

Comment: @maxpleaner - thanks, I guess what confused me was, in some cases everything was enclosed in class << self block, which made sense to me, that the class doesn't save any state and is like a utility method. but what would be the point of having one method to initialize class and rest of the methods as instance methods.

Comment: What you see here are class methods delegating to instance methods. But the opposite can sometimes be useful as well, for example read up on [`module_function`](https://read.prettyco.de/you-ll-love-module-function-ca5f05284310). Well, strictly speaking this doesn't _delegate_ but rather _copies_, but you could imagine how delegating would work instead.

Comment: Usually just for convenience

Comment: @Jose Castellanos - thanks for your response. some samples have all the methods inside the self block except the initialize method. what is the point of that? if you have multiple methods and you first do - >  new(params).doWork. we have to assign this to a variable and call another method say doSomethingelse function?

Comment: @tera : The concept is not really specific to Ruby: In most OOP languages, you have instance methods (bound to an instance of a class), and class methods (bound to the whole class). One way to define a class method in Ruby is using `def self.name`.